# Mapping a drive and accessing it from another process programmatically (as another user)

Tags: .net, vb.net, kiosk

I need to launch two processes, the first to map a drive (homedrive in my case) and the second to launch an application that will access that drive (notepad, for example). The machine is a kiosk machine that is logged in a with a kiosk user that has minimal permissions, therefore these processes need to be run as a different user (when a user accesses the machine they get a winforms form which takes their credentials). The way I first approached this was to do start two processes with Process.Start, the first running "net" and passing "use H: \homedrive /persistent:no" in order to map their drive, and the second running "notepad" both of these have credentials supplied and useshellexecute set to false. The problem with this is that each process seems to be separated and the drive is unable to be accessed from the notepad process.

My solution to this was to launch both processes from one Process.Start call, this solution launches "cmd" and passes "/c net use H: \homedrive /persistent:no & notepad". This works exactly as hoped and the homedrive is accessible from notepad, perfect. Except for the fact that the command prompt stays open in the background, I have attempted altering the window style to hidden or minimized however after some Googling seems that if you are running as a different user then this is not possible.

Has anyone else encountered something similar to this?

Comment: Do you really need to map? Notepad could access \homedrive directly.

Comment: Users log in through my application running on a kiosk machine, it should then map the drive using the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the impersonate function would work, where the application would be running as the current user but use their credentials for a particular one task; followed by returning to current user.

The full info is located at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx
the short version

```
Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal un As String, ByVal domain As String, ByVal pw As String, ByVal LogonType As Integer, ByVal LogonProvider As Integer, ByRef Token As IntPtr) As Boolean
Public Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
Dim tokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)
Dim strUserID, strPW as string
```